# Using Firebase & Amazon S3 with correct security setup

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

We are developing a web application based on Angular JS on front end and firebase in the backend. We are considering to use Amazon S3 service to store the images and other attachments. The users logged in on our application are allowed to upload. Only some uploads are readable by public.

As there is no server side execution with firebase, what is the correct procedure to do such a setup without statically exposing the credentials publicly on the front end?

If is it not possible, we are considering to run a node.js server which is generating the credentials dynamically and writing into firebase. The frontend can read and use this credentials to  upload the document to S3 bucket. But this is our last option.